# QListView detect scroll changes

Tags: qt, listview

I need to intercept when a QListView is scrolled by any means (scroll bar, mouse wheel etc..). I can not find a signal emitted in such case.

Is there some signal when a QListView is scrolled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the scrollbars (`QListView::horizontalScrollBar()` and `QListView::verticalScrollbar()`) and use the `QScrollBar::valueChanged(int value)` signal

Comment: As I had my class subclassed I have overridden QListView::scrollContentsBy and it's what I needed (in my case a simpler solution). I will mark yours as the accepted reply as it seems more general.